# Mathematical Series

Tags: contest-math, computational-complexity, totient-function

I have been solving a problem and after much simplification I have been able to convert it of the below form and am unable to reduce it further.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \phi(m*i) \left[\frac{n}{i}\right] $$

where $\phi(k)$ denotes Euler Totient Fucntion and
[x] denotes Greatest Integer Function and
m denotes a prime number

Here n is of the order $10^{9}$ so this must be solved either in O(constant) or O(logN).

Is it possible to reduce this furthur?

Thanks in advance :)))

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? An algebraic simplification or a way to compute this efficiently?

Comment: An algebric simplification

Comment: In view of another question posted earlier https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342567/summation-involving-eulers-totient-function/342610?noredirect=1#comment856432_342610 I guess there's a source for this problem. It would be better that you link the original problem.